# Error when i try to activate my discord bot

Tags: discord, bots

Keep getting this error when i try to activate my bot with the command "node bot.js" in the prompt:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'
←[90m    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:355:18)←[39m
←[90m    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1056:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m
```

This is my code in the bot.js file:

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
   token: auth.token,
   autorun: true
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    // Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
    // It will listen for messages that will start with `!`
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];
       
        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
            case 'The':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'Maurend'
                });
            break;
            // Just add any case commands if you want to.
         }
        bot.on('!DaSimo', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
        bot.uploadFile({
            to: themaurend,
            file: 'DaSimo.png'
        });
}
```

I can't find the syntax error, does it have to be in the bot file or can it be in some another file in the Bot folder like auth.json or package.json? Anyone can help?

Comment: You're missing a `)` at the very end of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a closing curly bracket.

```js
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    // Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
    // It will listen for messages that will start with `!`
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];
       
        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
            case 'The':
                bot.sendMessage({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'Maurend'
                });
            break;
            // Just add any case commands if you want to.
         }
        bot.on('!DaSimo', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
        bot.uploadFile({
            to: themaurend,
            file: 'DaSimo.png'
        });
   } // here to close the if
}) // and here to close bot.on
```